# How could I add the eight directions effects to my A star algorithm instead of 4 movements?

Tags: python, algorithm, shortest-path, path-finding, a-star

I'm working on `A-star algorithm` and I have implemented my code to move just in `four directions` as shown below the results with `fixed heuristic`:

```
[11, 11, 0, 4, 5]
############## Search is success

[0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
[1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
[2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
[3, -1, 8, 9, 10, 11]
[4, 5, 6, 7, -1, 12]

['V', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
['V', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
['V', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
['V', ' ', ' ', '>', '>', 'V']
['>', '>', '>', '^', ' ', '*']
```

I tried to calculate the `heuristic` by using `Euclid distance` as shown below:

```
h = math.sqrt((x - goal[0])**2 + (y - goal[1])**2)
```

And I added the `eight` movements as shown below with `delta` and `delta name`:

```
delta =      [[1, 0, 1],
              [0, 1, 1],
              [-1, 0, 1],
              [0, -1, 1],
              [-1, -1, math.sqrt(2)],
              [-1, 1, math.sqrt(2)],
              [1, -1, math.sqrt(2)],
              [1, 1, math.sqrt(2)]]

delta_name = ['^','\','/','<','V','>','\','/']
```

it gave me some errors are shown below:

1-

```
File "<ipython-input-24-224819b0ad4c>", line 55
    delta_name = ['^','\','/','<','V','>','\','/']
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

2-

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-bc33334a69ba> in <module>
    174 
    175 
--> 176 search()

<ipython-input-25-bc33334a69ba> in search()
    140         x2=x-delta[action[x][y]][0]
    141         y2=y-delta[action[x][y]][1]
--> 142         policy[x2][y2]= delta_name[action[x][y]]
    143         x=x2
    144         y=y2

IndexError: list index out of range
```

How could I fix them please? and Could you locate the movements to my delta please, which one is up, right, down....etc?

This is my code:

```
import random
Import math
grid = [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
heuristic = [[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4],
             [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3],
             [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2],
             [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
             [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]]
init = [0,0]                           
goal = [len(grid)-1,len(grid[0])-1]
#Below the four potential actions to the single field
'''
delta = [[-1 , 0],   #up 
         [ 0 ,-1],   #left
         [ 1 , 0],   #down
         [ 0 , 1]]   #right
'''

delta =      [[1, 0, 1],
              [0, 1, 1],
              [-1, 0, 1],
              [0, -1, 1],
              [-1, -1, math.sqrt(2)],
              [-1, 1, math.sqrt(2)],
              [1, -1, math.sqrt(2)],
              [1, 1, math.sqrt(2)]]


#delta_name = ['^','<','V','>']  #The name of above actions

delta_name = ['^','\','/','<','V','>','\','/']

cost = 1
def search():
    #open list elements are of the type [g,x,y]
    closed = [[0 for row in range(len(grid[0]))] for col in range(len(grid))]
    action = [[-1 for row in range(len(grid[0]))] for col in range(len(grid))]

    #We initialize the starting location as checked
    closed[init[0]][init[1]] = 1
    expand=[[-1 for row in range(len(grid[0]))] for col in range(len(grid))]

    # we assigned the cordinates and g value
    x = init[0]
    y = init[1]
    g = 0
    #h = heuristic[x][y]
    h = math.sqrt((x - goal[0])**2 + (y - goal[1])**2)
    f = g + h 

    #our open list will contain our initial value
    open = [[f, g, h, x, y]]
    found  = False   #flag that is set when search complete
    resign = False   #Flag set if we can't find expand
    count = 0

    #print('initial open list:')
    #for i in range(len(open)):
            #print('  ', open[i])
    #print('----')

    while found is False and resign is False:    
        #Check if we still have elements in the open list
        if len(open) == 0:    #If our open list is empty, there is nothing to expand.
            resign = True
            print('Fail')
            print('############# Search terminated without success')
            print()
        else: 
            #if there is still elements on our list
            #remove node from list
            open.sort()             #sort elements in an increasing order from the smallest g value up
            open.reverse()          #reverse the list
            next = open.pop()       #remove the element with the smallest g value from the list
            #print('list item')
            #print('next')

            #Then we assign the three values to x,y and g. Which is our expantion.
            x = next[3]
            y = next[4]
            g = next[1]

            expand[x][y] = count
            count+=1

            #Check if we are done
            if x == goal[0] and y == goal[1]:
                found = True
                print(next) #The three elements above this "if".
                print('############## Search is success')
                print()

            else:
                #expand winning element and add to new open list
                for i in range(len(delta)):       #going through all our actions the four actions
                    #We apply the actions to x and y with additional delta to construct x2 and y2
                    x2 = x + delta[i][0]
                    y2 = y + delta[i][1]

                    #if x2 and y2 falls into the grid
                    if x2 >= 0 and x2 < len(grid) and y2 >=0 and y2 <= len(grid[0])-1:

                        if closed[x2][y2] == 0 and grid[x2][y2] == 0:
                            g2 = g + cost            
                            #h2 = heuristic[x2][y2]
                            h2 = math.sqrt((x2 - goal[0])**2 + (y2 - goal[1])**2)
                            f2 = g2 + h2 

                            open.append([f2,g2,h2,x2,y2])   
                            #print('append list item')
                            #print([g2,x2,y2])
                            #Then we check them to never expand again
                            closed[x2][y2] = 1
                            action[x2][y2] = i

    for i in range(len(expand)):
        print(expand[i])
    print()

    policy=[[' ' for row in range(len(grid[0]))] for col in range(len(grid))]
    x=goal[0]
    y=goal[1]
    policy[x][y]='*'
    while x !=init[0] or y !=init[1]:
        x2=x-delta[action[x][y]][0]
        y2=y-delta[action[x][y]][1]
        policy[x2][y2]= delta_name[action[x][y]]
        x=x2
        y=y2
    for i in range(len(policy)):
        print(policy[i])

search()
```

Comment: Your problem is a typo: `delta_name = ['^','\','/','<','V','>','\','/']` should be `delta_name = ['^','\\','/','<','V','>','\\','/']`, as the backslash is a string escape character in Python, like in most programming languages. Please remove or update the question, as the problem isn't really about what you're asking, but just a typo.

Comment: @Grismar Ok Sir, about these strings, it really works perfectly. Could you give me the directions of my delta please, which one is up and which one is down .. etc?

Comment: I think that goes a bit beyond the scope of the question - perhaps you could formulate your question to be a bit more specific; however, I would recommend either setting a breakpoint at the offending line, or logging the value of `action[x][y]` just before it, so you can see what value is actually causing the error.

Comment: @Grismar I didn't get you Sir. What do you mean by a breakpoint at the offending?

Comment: Depending on your IDE, you should look up how to set a breakpoint if it supports them. Otherwise, I suggest adding `print` statements, or switching to an IDE that does support setting breakpoints (like PyCharm or Spyder). With 'the offending line', I meant the line that causes the error you're trying to fix, i.e. the line with `policy[x2][y2]= delta_name[action[x][y]]`.

Comment: @Grismar I got it Sir. Thank you so much dear.

Answer (score 1):

### Use syntax highlighting

In the line `delta_name = ['^','\','/','<','V','>','\','/']` you don't have a list of "characters" because in the second string the `\` character escapes the closing quote, so it doesn't get closed where you want it. Syntax highlighting in most editors would show you that.

If you want a string containing the single character `\` then you must write it as `'\\'`.

For more information, see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals - "The backslash () character is used to escape characters that otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, **backslash itself**, or the quote character."

Comment: Although your answer is correct, it's considered bad form to provide an 'answer' to questions that are really just a typo: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123741/should-questions-where-a-problem-arose-from-a-typo-be-closed

Comment: @Grismar I don't think that this is a typo (i.e. that the OP intended to write it that way but accidentally missed it) but instead a question "why does this line parse the way it does?" caused by lack of understanding of escaping in python string literals.

Comment: @Peteris The backslash is working good with me now, could you limit for me dear sir, the exact directions of my delta? Which one is up, or down, right ... etc?

Answer (score 0):

You are writing a string here and `'\'` here means another thing. 
For example `'\n'`, it means new line, `'\t'`, it means Tap or space.... etc. 
If you want to use it as a direction, you can use double-slash inside the string to cancel the effect of the backslash and to get what you want. `'\\'`. As mentioned above by other commentators.